# Trying to implement live web socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket

Purpose: when the http server receives the get value of the q variable, it sends its contents to all websocket clients. What am I missing?

```
let ws = require("nodejs-websocket")
let http = require('http');
let url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  let q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  let MSG = q.q;
  res.end('ok')
}).listen(80);

let server = ws.createServer(function (conn){

conn.sendText(MSG)

}).listen(3231)
```

Comment: I would recommend using socket io for this https://socket.io/

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by what you're missing? Is this not working as intended? Errors, clients not getting the broadcasted value?

Comment: `ws` package is the best for websockets